# css rules not apply on all the div

Tags: html, css

In style.css

```css
#descriptif_menu_01,
#descriptif_menu_02,
#descriptif_menu_03,
#descriptif_menu_04,
#descriptif_menu_05 {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgb(100,100,100);
  position: absolute;
  width:950px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 35px 50px;
  }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px){
  #descriptif_menu_01,
  #descriptif_menu_02,
  #descriptif_menu_03,
  #descriptif_menu_04,
  #descriptif_menu_05 {
    font-size:12px;
    width:650px;
    padding: 10px 50px;
  }
}
```

In HTML:

```html
<div id="menu_01" style="display: none;">
 <div class="onglets">
   <a class="bouton_close" onclick='#'></a>
 </div>
 
 <div id="descriptif_menu_01">
   <div class="titre">BARCO ONE CAMPUS HQ
    <div class="descriptif"> | Kortrijk</div>
   </div>   
 </div>
 <div id="plan">
  <a id="btn_360_exterieur" 
   onclick="#"></a>
  <a id="btn_360_reception" 
   onclick="#"></a>
  <a id="btn_360_restaurant" 
   onclick="#"></a>
  <a id="btn_360_projector" 
   onclick="#></a>
 </div>
 <div id="descriptif_plan">
  <div id="btn_360_exterieur_2"><h3>EXTERIOR VIEW</h3></div>
  <div id="btn_360_reception_2"><h3>RECEPTION</h3></div>
  <div id="btn_360_restaurant_2"><h3>RESTAURANT</h3></div>
  <div id="btn_360_projector_2"><h3>LOBBY</h3></div>
 </div>
</div>


<div id="menu_02" style="display:none;">
 <div class="onglets">
   <a class="bouton_close" onclick='#'></a>
 </div>
 
 <div id="descriptif_menu_02">
   <div class="titre">BARCO ONE CAMPUS HQ
    <div class="descriptif"> | Kortrijk</div>
   </div>   

   </br>
   BLALBLALA</br>
   </br>
MORE BLALBLABLABLA.
   <div id="texte_descriptif"> <img src="textures/texte.png"/></div>   
 
 </div>
</div>
```

when my phone is on landscape, everything works.
when my phone is on portrait, #descriptif_menu_01,#descriptif_menu_03,#descriptif_menu_04 are apply, not #descriptif_menu_02, #descriptif_menu_05.

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what is the issue exactly so i can help you ?

Comment: everything working dear, but you set `@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px)` so there will be no difference between _landscape_ and _portrait_, I think you have to change `max-width` value to fit your needs, **currently your `media query` will fire only when screen size < 1280px**

Comment: I just try on firefox and it's working. But using chrome on my smartphone, i still have the prb....